# <p:datatable> column sizes is messed up after update

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, width

I'm using Primefaces 4.0 and JSF 2.1. when i fire the search action from my `<p:commandButton>`, the table is populated with correct data and everything is fine, only columns width is messed up.

Before update :
[image]

After update :
[image]

`<p:commandButton>` code :

```
<p:commandButton id="searcher" value="Rechercher"  action="#{examenListBean.search}"  update="tabexam"/>
```

`<p:dataTable>` code :

```
<p:dataTable id="tabexam"
                             paginatorPosition="bottom"
                             var="exam"
                             value="#{examenListBean.listexam}"
                             widgetVar="examTable"
                             emptyMessage="aucun résultat trouvé pour votre recherche"
                             filteredValue="#{examenListBean.filteredexams}"
                             paginator="true"
                             rows="30" 
                             paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"  
                             rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15,30"
                             resizableColumns="true">
```

Comment: May be its because of resizableColumns

Comment: Actually even with that removed , i'm still getting the same problem.

Comment: May be you Description is to long as i seen in the datatable

Comment: If the description is very big the other column just got shrink i thing

Comment: i think the problem is not with the larger column 'Dossier patient' becuz it has only a simple 16X16 png icon, i wonder why it got that big in the first place.

Comment: place your datatable code

Comment: actually when i removed the resizableColumns attributes, its better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the `resizableColumns="true"` and it solved the problem.